# How to redirect url with added url parameters

Tags: django

I have a workout calendar app where if a user goes to `/workoutcal`, I want them to be redirected to `workoutcal/<today's year>/<today's month>`. That means I want them to be redirected to this route, should they go to `/workoutcal`:

```
url(r'^(?P<year>[0-9]+)/(?P<month>[1-9]|1[0-2])$', views.calendar, name='calendar'),
```

So how can I write a new url pattern in urls.py that does something like:

```
url(r'^$', RedirectView().as_view(url=reverse_lazy(),todays_year, todays_month)),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subclass `RedirectView`, override `get_redirect_url`, and reverse the url there.

```
class MonthRedirectView(RedirectView):
    def get_redirect_url(*args, **kwargs):
        today = timezone.now()
        return reverse(calendar, args=[today.year, today.month])
```

Then include your view in the URL pattern:

```
url(r'^$', MonthRedirectView().as_view()),
```

Answer (score 1):

I found another solution to my problem, which is making a view that simply calls the calendar with the right arguments:

the url:

```
url(r'^$', views.redirect_to_calendar),
```

the redirect view:

```
def redirect_to_calendar(request):
    today = timezone.now()
    return calendar(request, year = today.year, month = today.month)
```

the view we serve to the user:

```
def calendar(request, year = None, month = None):

    ## A bunch of server logic 

    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your RedirectView is in your app's urls.py:

```
url(r'^(?P<year>[0-9]+)/(?P<month>[1-9]|1[0-2])$', views.calendar, name='calendar'),
url(r'^$', RedirectView().as_view(url='{}/{}'.format(todays_year, todays_month)),
```

EDIT: This assumes that `todays_year` and `todays_month` are calculated when a user goes to `/workoutcal/`, which they aren't (they're loaded at URL load time). See Alasdair's answer.

Comment: If you do this then `todays_year` and `todays_month` will be calculated when the URLs are loaded. Next month you will find that users are redirected to the out-of-date URL.

Comment: Good observation, I wasn't considering that.